# Required: large number (max 1000 digits) stored in string modulo 11

Tags: c++, string, modulo, largenumber

I have a question, which is to find the modulo 11 of a large number. The number is stored in a string whose maximum length is 1000. I want to code it in c++. How should i go about it?

I tried doing it with long long int, but its impossible that it can handle the corner case value.

Comment: Use the GMP library.

Comment: A number in decimal system a_0+a_1*10+a_2*10^2+...+a_n*10^n has the same remainder modulo 11 as a_n-a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}-....+(-1)^na_0. That the number of 1000 digits doesn't fit into an int is not a problem, since the latter sum will definitely fit.

Comment: Re: "The number is stored in a string..." -- there are an infinite number of possible ways to store a number in a string. Which one is used here?

Comment: The number is stored starting with the most significant digit on the position 0 of the string and the least significant digit in the last position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number written in decimal positional system as a_na_{n-1}...a_0 is the number

a_n*10^n+a_{n-1}*10^{n-1}+...+a_0

Note first that this number and the number

a_0-a_{1}+a_{2}+...+(-1)^{n}a_n

which is the sum of its digits with alternating signs have the same remainder after division by 11. You can check that by subtracting both numbers and noting that the result is a multiple of 11.

Based on this, if you are given a string consisting of the decimal representation of a number, then you can compute the remainder modulo 11 like this:

```
int remainder11(const std::string& s) {
  int result{0};
  bool even{true};
  for (int i = s.length() - 1; i > -1; --i) {
    result += (even ? 1 : -1) * ((int)(s[i] - '0'));
    even = !even;
  }
  return ((result % 11) + 11) % 11;
}
```

Comment: There are two problems with your code. First, you should start looping from the least significant digit since `even` is `true` at beginning (this can vary, however, depending on how you represent the number, I am assuming human-readable format). Second, **modulo operator in c++ don't produce the result you want when used on negative numbers**. For example `-1 % 3 == -1`. Try the string `"91"`, would break your code. Maybe you should return `((result % 11) + 11) % 11`?

Comment: @KaenbyouRin You are right. I thought that C++ had corrected that, but it was Python the one that corrected the modulo.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the magic (math) trick.

First imagine you have a decimal number that consists only of `1`s.

Say `111111`, for example. It is obvious that `111111 % 11` is `0`. (Since you can always write it as the sum of a series of `11*10^n`). This can be generalized to all integers consists purely of even numbers of ones. (e.g. `11`, `1111`, `11111111`). For those with odd number of ones, just subtract one from it and you will get a `10` times some number that consists of odd numbers of one (e.g `111=1+11*10`), so their modulo to `11` would be `1`.

A decimal number can be always written as the form of [image]

where `a0` is the least significant digit and `an` is the most significant digit. Note that `10^n` can be written as `10^n - 1 + 1`, and `10^n - 1` is a number consists of `n` nines. If `n` is even, then you will get `9` times some even number of ones, and its modulo to `11` is always `0`. If `n` is odd, then we get `9` times some odd number of ones, and its modulo to `11` is always `9`. And don't forget we've still got a `+1` after `10^n - 1 + 1` so we need to add `a` to the result.

We are very close to our results now: we just have to add things up and do a final modulo to `11`. The pseudo-code would be like:

```
Initialize sum to 0.
Initialize index to 0.
For every digit d from the least to most significant:
    If the index is even, sum += d
    Otherwise, sum += 10 * d
    ++index
    sum %= 11
Return sum % 11
```

Comment: Note that adding `10*d`, which is the same as `11*d - d` is the same as just adding `-d` for the sake of computing remainders modulo 11. The advantage of this is that it keeps the `sum` a little smaller and therefore a larger range of input can be treated without having overflow.

Comment: @embeddedPy Just add a bit of code to mod the result every loop. Would keep the result smaller.